# Previous Image on a slider

Tags: javascript, oop, button, slider

I'm trying to do a image slider, but I'm struggling with a previous button, all the code, expect for the previous button, is working just fine. Could you help me please?

```
<body>
    <div>
    <img name="slide" width="80%" height="auto">
    <button id="nextImg">next</button>
    <button id="prevImg">prev</button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
var i = 0;
var image = [];
var time = 1000;

image[0] = 'image1.png'
image[1] = 'image2.jpg'
image[2] = 'image3.jpg'

function changeImg() {
    document.slide.src = image[i];
 
    if (i < image.length - 1) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }

    setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}

nextImg.onclick = function() {
    document.slide.src = image[i];
 
    if (i < image.length - 1) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
}

prevImg.onclick = function() {
    document.slide.src = image[i];
 
    if (i > image.length - 1) {
        i--;
    } else {
        i = 2;
    }
}


window.onload = changeImg;
```

I tried different approaches but the outcome is always the same, or it doesnt do anything or just go to the next image and not to the previous as expected.

Comment: Your if condition seems to be wrong. Try "if (i > 0)" instead of "if (i > image.length - 1)"

Comment: The first time i click it goes to the next image but then it start to work as expect, could be something wrong on other part of the code?

Comment: Your `changeImg` sets the current image, and then modifies `i` to point to the _next_ image in the sequence. Your prev button function then assigns the image corresponding to the current `i` - which _already_ is the _next_ image.

Comment: You should do this the other way around - modify your `i` according to the "direction" first, and then show that image. Also, your `changeImg` and your `nextImg.onclick` function do almost the same thing - so you should not write that same code twice. Put the part that moves to the next image into a separate function - and then use that as you next button click callback function, _and_ call it inside your `changeImg` as well.

Comment: And since you already took measures to work with the _actual_ number of images you have in your array in all other places, that `i = 2;` there at the end should not be hard-coded. Make use of `image.length` in that place as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
prevImg.onclick = function() {    
    
    if (i > 0) i--;
    else i = 2;
    
    document.slide.src = image[i];
}
```